# Why does App Engine serves non-default version?

Tags: flutter, google-app-engine, web-applications, gcloud

I'm using the standard environment of app engine.
I've deployed my app many times in the past, but today, although I've deployed new features App Engine, it serves an old version.

1. I've deleted all the versions and redeployed the app.
2. Verified in consol that the source files are the correct ones.
3. When deploy the (only) default version by its id I see the updated app (gcloud app browse -v VESION_ID), but when I load the app regularly (gcloud app browse) I get an old version that not exists anymore.
4. If I hard-reload (ctrl+shift+F5) I get another old version (different from the one it serve by default) but when I reload the page again (ctrl+F5) the other old version come back.
   Any help would be appreciated to make App engine serve the most updated version.

Comment: Did you configure traffic splitting with an older version? Also, did you try deploying the new version with `--promote` flag?

Comment: Any update on the case or if what the other comment worked?